# Как масштабировать размеры иконок svg

Tags: html, css, svg, icon, inkscape

Вот есть код:

```html
<style>
    .alignlef {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.625em;
}
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <symbol id="beac" viewBox="0 0 100 100"> 
        <path fill="#85D4EE" d="M28.947,
                                 56.486
                                c15.685-11.277,
                                 23.532-21.592,
                                 27.222-29.46c4.311-9.193,
                                 0.561-20.589-8.845-24.413
                                C36.268-1.88,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486S21.678-1.907,
                                 10.623,
                                 2.588C1.217,
                                 6.412-2.533,
                                 17.808,
                                 1.778,
                                 27.001
                                C5.468,
                                 34.868,
                                 13.262,
                                 45.21,
                                 28.947,
                                 56.486z"/>  
    </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
        <use width ="256" height="256" xlink:href="#beac" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="144" height="144" viewBox="0 0 144 144">
        <use width ="144" height="144" xlink:href="#beac" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <use width ="128" height="128" xlink:href="#beac" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="96" height="96" viewBox="0 0 96 96">
        <use width ="96" height="96" xlink:href="#beac" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="72" height="72" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
     <use width ="72" height="72" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
     <use width ="64" height="64" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
     <use width ="48" height="48" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
     <use width ="32" height="32" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <use width ="24" height="24" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
<div class="alignlef"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
     <use width ="16" height="16" xlink:href="#beac" /></svg>
</div>
```

При размерах `256` пикселей размер svg иконки не `256 пикселей`, а где-то `~140`
При указании `128`, тоже не `128` и т.д.
Почему так происходит?
 Я уже перечитал все эти мануалы, в примерах их иконки все нормально отображаются с размерами, а почему эта не работает как надо?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Масштаб определяется соотношением `viewport / viewBox`, где `viewport` это `width="X"` `height="Y"`

В вашем примере масштабирование применяется последовательно  несколько раз.
Очень легко запутаться. Поэтому я максимально упрощу ваш пример и поэтапно буду усложнять до практического применения

- Ниже пример, где применяется масштабирование только один раз в шапке
  svg файла

`viewport / viewBox` = 100/100=1. Масштаб будет - **1:1** То есть как нарисовано в векторном редакторе, так и будет отражаться на дисплее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине векторного редактора видно, что физически иконка имеет габариты - `56.6 х 56.6px`

- Теперь запускаем этот же файл в браузере. И для наглядности я добавил
  красный прямоугольник,  через стили в шапке файла, который показывает
  границы SVG файла.

  `style="border:1px solid red;"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red;">
           <path fill="#85D4EE" d="M28.947,
                                 56.486
                                c15.685-11.277,
                                 23.532-21.592,
                                 27.222-29.46c4.311-9.193,
                                 0.561-20.589-8.845-24.413
                                C36.268-1.88,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486S21.678-1.907,
                                 10.623,
                                 2.588C1.217,
                                 6.412-2.533,
                                 17.808,
                                 1.778,
                                 27.001
                                C5.468,
                                 34.868,
                                 13.262,
                                 45.21,
                                 28.947,
                                 56.486z"/>
```

Границы svg определяет `viewport` это - `width="100" height="100"`

Из примеров видно, что иконка `56 х 56px` не полностью занимает `viewport` - `100 х 100px`

*Это очень плохо, так как эти свободные пространства добавляют отступы от других элементов верстки HTML*

**Убираем лишние отступы**

- Для этого уменьшаем `viewport` до размеров иконки

`width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 58 58"`

Смотрим результаты в векторном редакторе и в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Пример в браузере*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="56" height="56" viewBox="0 0 58 58"
style="border:1px solid red;">
           <path fill="#85D4EE" d="M28.947,
                                 56.486
                                c15.685-11.277,
                                 23.532-21.592,
                                 27.222-29.46c4.311-9.193,
                                 0.561-20.589-8.845-24.413
                                C36.268-1.88,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486S21.678-1.907,
                                 10.623,
                                 2.588C1.217,
                                 6.412-2.533,
                                 17.808,
                                 1.778,
                                 27.001
                                C5.468,
                                 34.868,
                                 13.262,
                                 45.21,
                                 28.947,
                                 56.486z"/>  
         
   
</svg>
```

### Масштабирование иконок до требуемых размеров

**Размер `256 x 256px`**

Для этого увеличиваем размер `viewport` до требуемых размеров

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 58 58"`

- Проверяем в векторном редакторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Проверяем в браузере

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 58 58"
style="border:1px solid red;">
           <path fill="#85D4EE" d="M28.947,
                                 56.486
                                c15.685-11.277,
                                 23.532-21.592,
                                 27.222-29.46c4.311-9.193,
                                 0.561-20.589-8.845-24.413
                                C36.268-1.88,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486S21.678-1.907,
                                 10.623,
                                 2.588C1.217,
                                 6.412-2.533,
                                 17.808,
                                 1.778,
                                 27.001
                                C5.468,
                                 34.868,
                                 13.262,
                                 45.21,
                                 28.947,
                                 56.486z"/>  
         
   
</svg>
```

**Размер `128 x 128px`**

- проверяем в векторном редакторе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Делаем рабочую версию приложения

**Основное правило последовательных масштабирований в одном файле SVG**

В шапке файла SVG задается самый большой viewport - это прямоугольная область, которую видит пользователь на экране. Если задали `width="256"` `height="256"`, то последующие масштабирования, которые идут в коде ниже могут только уменьшать размер этой области.

Пример с 3 иконками `256x256; 128x128; 64x64`

```css
  .alignlef {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.625em;
} 
path {
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 58 58" >
    <symbol id="beac">         
   <path fill="none" d="M28.947,
                                 56.486
                                c15.685-11.277,
                                 23.532-21.592,
                                 27.222-29.46c4.311-9.193,
                                 0.561-20.589-8.845-24.413
                                C36.268-1.88,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486,
                                 28.947,
                                 8.486S21.678-1.907,
                                 10.623,
                                 2.588C1.217,
                                 6.412-2.533,
                                 17.808,
                                 1.778,
                                 27.001
                                C5.468,
                                 34.868,
                                 13.262,
                                 45.21,
                                 28.947,
                                 56.486z"/>    
  </symbol> 
  
  
</svg>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 58 58">
        <use  xlink:href="#beac" fill="dodgerblue" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 58 58">
        <use  xlink:href="#beac" fill="crimson" />
    </svg> 
</div>  

<div class="alignlef">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 58 58">
        <use  xlink:href="#beac" fill="purple" />
    </svg> 
</div>
```

Comment: Поставлю обязательно, но вот осталась одна вещь-снизу и сверху остались небольшие отступы, как победить их?

Comment: а почему нельзя этот зазор убрать?
Забавно. я масштабировал иконку по урокам на вашем сайте

Comment: То есть она нарисовала не в пропорции, так?
А можно тогда зная этот исходный код свг поправить ее до нужных пропорций?

Comment: Вот по рекомендации я уже понял. Но как их выбрать? везде черти что

Comment: Понял. все. сейчас будет.